# Online Payment solution to account to account transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, payment

I would like to know if there is a possibility of transferring money from my sellers customer to my seller directly without me getting involved?

Setup is like this

I've my website

Sellers register and sell their items

Customers register and buy sellers items..

What i want is to take money from customers account (be it credit card / debit card) and transfer directly to sellers account. Simply money shouldn't be deposited into my account and then transfer to the sellers.

I am using Ruby on Rails to build the application. Any payment gateway which supports this?

rgds,

Kannan R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to transfer money from account to account (RTGS / Visa)... If that is the case, i don't think Payment gateways support that.

If you want to have a setup like this,
each of your sellers have their own payment gateway account (like authorize.net / paypal / etc) then you can use their account credentials to use the corresponding API and take money directly into their account from the customers

In which case you are not involved in the payment (though you are providing the service).

If you are not restricting your sellers to use a set of payment gateways... then you'll have to implement the logic of which seller using which payment gateway, use the corresponding credentials, and use the corresponding API, etc which i believe is a huge task !!!Congrats with that